# What do you call someone who won't compromise and will do everything to win 100%?

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

Is there an idiom that allows you to express this idea? I am either trying to find an idiom, or a word, or an adjective that I can use in a phrase during a casual conversation. As long as you manage to convey the idea in a good-sounding way, I would be okay with anything.

The only way I could express this is the following way:

> This guy would not give any inch, and is ready to die for it.

The above doesn't sound too idiomatic and the "it" may be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: [This speech in the movie Any Given Sunday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1yWSePMqsk) seems directly related to your question and may be worth watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [perfectionist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfectionist), [overachiever](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overachiever), or [hard-liner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hard-line) for a noun.

[Uncompromising](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uncompromising) would work as an adjective.

As for idioms, this could work:

> **He doesn't know how to lose.** (Implies that he literally hasn't experienced loss, he doesn't know how to act appropriately when he does lose, or that he is incapable of not giving everything to win)

Different words would be used in different contexts; for example, a "hard-liner" is usually used in reference to politics or other ideological stances. The point of view is also very important, as "hard-liner" is typically used to describe someone you don't agree with and/or criticize rather than one of your allies or friends.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion "He won't give an inch." is correct and idiomatic.  "He is ready to die for it" only works if we have a specific thing that "it" refers to.

But the language you use in the question title is simple and unambiguous:

> He never compromises and will do everything to win.

There is no need to use a figure of speech or a saying. We try to encourage students not to use clichés, and many "idioms" are best avoided as being clichés.